# Can I add more than on button to a java JFrame?

Tags: java, button, jframe

I am facing a problem, I want to add more than a button to a JFrame, but it only takes the last one and puts it into the frame, a sample of my code is below:

```
String isName = "";

JFrame frame = new JFrame(isName);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

String childAmb = "PDA276";

for (int j=0; j<3; j++){

    if (childAmb.matches("Phone\\w\\w\\w"))
        fancyButtonCreator(childAmb, new ImageIcon ("src/phone.gif"), frame);

    else if (childAmb.matches("PDA\\w\\w\\w"))
        fancyButtonCreator(childAmb, new ImageIcon ("src/pda.gif"), frame);

    else if (childAmb.matches("PC\\w\\w\\w"))
        fancyButtonCreator(childAmb, new ImageIcon ("src/pc.gif"), frame);
    }

   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setBounds(100, 200, 200, 200);
```

Thank you.

---

Comment: Can you show us what is happening in `fancyButtonCreator`?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a layout-manager, only one, the last component added will show up.

```
frame.setLayout (new FlowLayout ());
frame.add (new JButton ("foo"));
frame.add (new JButton ("bar"));
```

Comment: Hmm? When I don't have a layout manager (`setLayout(null);`), I have to specify coordinates, and they are all visible.

Comment: But you should have an LayoutManager. If you use an AbsoluteLayout, you have to specify coordinates, yes. Where is the question? You should, however, prefer regular LayoutManagers, which allow the  User to resize Components.

Answer (score 1):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for examples.

You can start with the FlowLayout.